# Split an image into left and right parts and fill the browser

Tags: html, css, css-float, parallax

I'm trying to split an image into a left and right side. I did this but I want the div to be centered and fill the browser so the images are edge to edge and be responsive. Right now it's all flush to the left.

I put a border so you can see that it's in fact two images put together to make one - 600x900 each.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/vnc522vu/3/

HTML

```
 <div id="centercontainer">


 <div id="scrollablecontainer">

    <img id="leftside" class="halfCompositionLeft" src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/pool_left.jpg?_subject_uid=9047713&w=AAC25lQ4ebCI8ajjRKwfi_TANvxEYQruCRN5PQDEEZ70Uw">


    <img id="rightside" class="halfCompositionRight" src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/pool_right.jpg?_subject_uid=9047713&w=AABZnKZrODSr9rGU5kOX7q2EHycNMAqq-mvlUxn0T5tVAg">


    </div>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollableSectionContainer section>img {
    position:absolute;
}

.centercontainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollablecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

   .halfCompositionLeft {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:600px;
    height:900px;       
}
.halfCompositionRight {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 600px;
     width: 600px;
    height: 900px;
    border:#FFF solid thin; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#halfCompositionLeft{
    position: absolute; //Absolute Positioning.
    top: 0px; //Top of the page.
    left: 0px; //Leftmost side.
    width: 50%; //Fill half the page.
    height: 100%; //Fill page vertically. 
}

#halfCompositionRight{
    position: absolute; //Absolute Positioning.
    top: 0px; //Top of the page.
    left: 50%; //Start halfway through the page.
    width:50%; //Fill rest of page.
    height: 100%; //Fill page vertically. 
}
```

That uses CSS percentages rather than pixel values, which dynamically sets size and position based on page size. To complete this, simply make the full box 100% wide and 100% high, and it will fill the page appropriately.

**EDIT:** CSS for placing div parallel underneath:

```
#halfCompositionLeft2{
    position: absolute; //Absolute Positioning.
    top: 100%; //Similar, but at the bottom of the page, under the top div.
    left: 0px; //Leftmost side.
    width: 50%; //Fill half the page.
    height: 100%; //Fill page vertically. 
}

#halfCompositionRight2{
    position: absolute; //Absolute Positioning.
    top: 100%; //Similar, but at the bottom of the page, under the top div.
    left: 50%; //Start halfway through the page.
    width:50%; //Fill rest of page.
    height: 100%; //Fill page vertically. 
}
```

Comment: wow! is there a way to stack another similar div underneath this. When I do that, it goes behind the first one because of the position:absolute, but I'd like it to appear underneath

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I will answer your question to the best of my abilities.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/vnc522vu/4/ if you see the HTML I just duplicated the div. I'd like to just have another image inside of a div below this one, with the same style. But I'd like it to appear underneath the first div.

Comment: I see. This is excellent. One last point. Is there a way to use pixels instead of percentages so that the aspect ratio of the image doesn't get squished by the browser.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! what you need to do is ONLY set the height, and separate the 2 images from each-other. This is the only way to keep the images apart and maintain aspect ratio, but may clip the image. Be sure to set the width to auto, and if you have a large enough image, it should scale to a reasonable size.

Comment: That works for the right image but not the left image. The right image is flush next to the vertical line down the center, but the left image is pushed all the way to the left. I'd like the right side of the left image to also be flush to the vertical line down the center. http://screencast.com/t/C8CrLeaQ1hQ

Comment: Hmm... That looks like a problem with the root container, you should look into the styling for that. Glad I could help you though!